# Multi-group CFA analysis - two different outcomes

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I have four **first-order factors** explained by one **second-order factor**. I am going to test the second-order factor across **two different groups**, one in Poland (group 1) and one in Spain (group 2). Also, the factor will be tested among **two different outcomes**, the outcomes are both about addictive behaviour: smoking (group 1, Poland) and drinking (group 2, Spain).

**Question 1:**
I am planning to use multi-group CFA analysis to evaluate **configural and metric invariance**. Is this the right approach for my research design?

**Question 2:**
I want to verify that my construct is associated with addictive behaviours in general, so it makes sense to me that it should be valid **regardless of the specific type of addictive behaviour**. However, my concern is that it is going to make noise in the data, because the two behaviours still have some unique variance. **What is the best approach to address this?**

Thank you

Comment: This seems tricky to me, because if you find variance, you don't know whether to attribute it to the country, or the substance.  I'm not an expert but it seems to me that the nature of addiction to alcohol and tobacco are very different.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. Cross-cultural comparisons are very common, the point is to check that parameters are equivalent across populations. The second-order is a broad concept and I am confident, from the literature, that it explains variance in both behaviours. Might it be a multilevel, and not a multi-group, a better approach?

Comment: Yes, you can compare a scale across cultures, or you can compare two conceptualizations of the same scale within a culture, but it is not clear to me that you can do both at the same time. Unique variance is not going to be your problem here (IMHO).

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, if you know someone who could have a better idea I would really appreciate if you could share the link of this page with him/her. All the best.

Comment: Try the semnet mailing list?